# how to model the JS in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this json

```
    var myNameSpace = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    function MyController($scope){ 
    $scope.phoneBookData = [{ name : "book1",
                 contacts : [{   "name" : "con1",
                                 "age" , 20 },
                                 {"name" : "con2",
                                 "age" : 30

                            },
                     { "name" : book2,
                         contacts : [{   "name" : "con11",
                                 "age" , 25 },
                                 {"name" : "con22",
                                 "age" : 40

                            } }]
     }
```

The HTML should look like label for the name and table for the contacts

```
     <div ng-controller = "MyControler">
     <li class ="phone books" ng-repeat="item in phoneBookData"
     <Label>{{item.name}}</Label>

       <li {{item.contacts.name}}></li>
       <li {{item.contacts.age}}></li>
      </div>
```

it didn't work do I need to add more ng-repeat?

Comment: You're missing a closing `<li>` tag - and format your post please, it's very hard to read.

Comment: Closing li tag is not very necessary, but an ul would definitely not hurt.  Also, format code pls, and add plunkr.

Comment: @MihalyKR -- Closing it is necessary...

Comment: You're right - now I see what you mean, overlooked that it doesnt have the closing bracket. Looked like it only misses the </li> part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with needing to fix all the typos, yes you do need another ng-repeat for the contacts array

```js
var myNameSpace = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myNameSpace.controller('MyController', function ($scope){ 
  $scope.phoneBookData = [{ 
    name : "book1",
    contacts : [{ 
      "name" : "con1",
      "age": 20 
    },{
      "name" : "con2",
      "age" : 30
    }]
  },{ 
    "name" : "book2",
    contacts : [{   
      "name" : "con11",
      "age": 25 
    },{
      "name" : "con22",
      "age" : 40
    }]
  }];
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller = "MyController">
     <div class ="phone books" ng-repeat="item in phoneBookData">
       <label>{{item.name}}</label>  
       <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="contact in item.contacts">
           <div>{{contact.name}}</div>
           <div>{{contact.age}}</div>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is full of errors. You are spelling the name of your controller two different ways which is likely your problem. Your json is also broken. Working code

```js
    var myNameSpace = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        function MyController($scope){ 
        $scope.phoneBookData = [{ name : "book1",
                                   contacts : [{   "name" : "con1",
                                                   "age" , 20 },
                                               {"name" : "con2",
                                                 "age" : 30

                                                },
                                                { "name" : book2,
                                                   contacts : [{   "name" : "con11",
                                               "age" , 25 },
                                     {"name" : "con22",
                                     "age" : 40

                                } }]
         }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-controller=MyController ng-app=myApp>
     <li class ="phone books" ng-repeat="item in phoneBookData"
     <Label>{{item.name}}</Label>

       <li {{item.contacts.name}}></li>
       <li {{item.contacts.age}}></li>
      </div>
```

Comment: You could also fix HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Insane number of errors in such a small code:

- `MyController` != `MyControler`
- `"name" : book2` = improper JSON (should be `"name" : "book2"` unless `book2` is a variable)
- `<li class ="phone books" ng-repeat="item in phoneBookData"` - needs closing
- count the open and closed square braces in `$scope.phoneBookData` (`[` and `]`), don't even want to talk about the curly ones - again, you need to close what you open
- `<li {{item.contacts.name}}></li>` Are you sure you want the name as an element attribute. Shouldn't it be `<li>{{item.contacts.name}}</li>` instead?
- `<li {{item.contacts.age}}></li>` The same as above

Most of those errors are shown in a browser console. Or you could see them in the source if it was formatted for humans.

To get the contacts in the table for each book, you need another ng-repeat for it.

I **strongly** suggest learning JavaScript and HTML before working in AngularJS.